# Running multiple streams using Icecast2 on Ubuntu

Tags: icecast, icecast2

I've recently taken on consultancy for a company that has the following setup:

- Windows Server A, published on the internet, running Icecast version 1.3.4 on port 8000.
- Many "source" streamers scattered across the territory (more than 200), each streaming to their own IP address and port 8000.
- The different streamers are on a subnet visible from Server A but not published on the internet.

Customers who want to listen to the audio of Streamer X, cannot connect directly to the source stream X, but they connect to Server A by composing a URL as follows:
*ServerA_IP*:8000//StreamerX_IP_:8000, and this way they listen to Streamer X's audio (i.e: 10.1.2.3:8000//172.4.5.6:8000).
If a customer wants to simultaneously listen to Streamer Y's audio, he can do so at the address *ServerA_IP*:8000//StreamerY_IP_:8000

I hope I have been clear so far. The Icecast server on Server A allows listening to multiple source streams by simply entering the correct URL.

Now I need to install a new Ubuntu server instead of Server A and install Icecast2 on it. The source streamers network is not static, but it can change over time, so it's not possible to prepare a static configuration file where to write every single IP. Is it possible to replicate the same thing I described above? I've made some attempts (using the same logic to compose URLs), but I haven't succeeded.

I installed Icecast2 on Ubuntu 22.04 and I tried to connect to remote streamers using the *ServerA_IP*:8000//StreamerX_IP:8000 logic to compose URL for listening the audio from a browser.
I expect to listen audio from my browser using that kind of urls and I expect to be able to listen multiple stream at a time, from multiple browser sessions.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you in advance

Comment: either on demand relays and update config and SIGHUP to update them OR go for a reverse proxy. The latter is very tricky, but someone posted a very detailed complex nginx config in an answer here once.